# Symfony Task Unexpected Memory

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, wso2, php-5.2

I am using `Symfony` task php5.2. Here is a portion of my code:

array of images

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v)
{
    abc(); // function call which will cope images from one server to another
           // by using file_get_content in a php variable and using api(wso).
    echo memory_get_usage();
}
```

problem is `memory_get_usage();` always returning same value but when i am using top command memory is increasing nonstop.

Is there any bug in symfony task or php5.2 or wso.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `memory_get_usage(true)`?

Also, have you considered that it might not be PHP that is using the memory? But some other library you are using?

Comment: Edit your question and place the output of top, when you have high load.